# network folder share issue in Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, windows-xp

I am using Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I want to share a disk folder and I want users to be able to access directly (e.g. using `\\10.10.10.123\shared` in Windows resource explorer) without using user name and password. Guest account does not work for me since it needs user name (Guest). Any solutions?

BTW: the same solution for Windows XP is also ok.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need at least a user name as there can't be a Windows user account without a name.
By tweaking security you get along without a password though.

Comment: Any solutions to access without a username and password? Solutions for Windows XP is ok.

Comment: Try to add "Everyone" on the share permissions and NTFS permissions of  your folder

Comment: I have added, but still need at least a user name. Any ideas to access the network share directly (using \\10.10.10.123\share directly from resource explorer) without a username?